# Make Cortana commands unambiguous?

Tags: xbox-one

Is there a trick to making commands clear enough that Cortana will not ask, "Which one?" I've got two scenarios that are frequently irritating me. When I say, "Hey Cortana, go to TV," she responds with:

*Which one?*

1. *TV*
2. *Movies & TV*

Same thing happens when I ask her to open Forza Horizon 2, where option 2 for that is the FH2 Fast & Furious game.

How can I get Cortana to open these apps without the "Which one?" back and forth?

Comment: If there *is* a solution, I suspect it would take longer than just answering Cortana's question.